# iOS hiding keyboard on "Return" press, resignFirstResponder vs endEditing

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I was searching for hiding the iOS keyboard when you press "return", and about half the answers are to use `self.view.endEditing(true)` and the other half `textField.resignFirstResponder()`. Is one a better way than the other?

For reference or anyone coming here from Google or something, you need to add `UITextFieldDelegate` to your class inheritance, add `self.<your_TF_var_name>.delegate = self` in viewDidLoad(), then make a function

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return false
//OR
     textField.resignFirstResponder()
     return true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it doesn't really matter which you use though technically, using `textField.resignFirstResponder()` is more efficient because you already know that is the text field you need to resign.

The call to `self.view.endEditing(true)` is going to have to figure out what the current first responder is and then call `resignFirstResponder` on it.

My general rule of thumb is to use `resignFirstResponder` if you have a reference to a specific view you wish to resign. And use `endEditing` if you don't and you just want the current first responder to be resigned.

On a side note, you should return `false` from `textFieldShouldReturn` in either case. There is an edge case where returning `true` can lead to a newline being added to a `UITextView` after resigning the `UITextField`. So as a rule I always return `false`.